# How to Convert BinaryData to File in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary-data

Actually I have saved some files like .`pdf`,.`txt`,.`doc`,.`xls` by converting them to `<Binary data>` in my `SQL SERVER DB` through `FileUploadControl`.
Now, I want to Convert the `<Binary data>` back to Normal and give an option for user to Download (or) View that data.

I have tried some thing like this for the .`txt` files

```
var filedata = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_QUESTION_REPLIES
                                    where xx.ID == FileID
                                    select xx).FirstOrDefault();

string fileextension = filedata.FILE_EXTENSION.ToString();
string fileName = filedata.ANSWER_TEXT.ToString() + fileextension;
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])filedata.FILE_DATA;
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

I am getting an error like :

> *Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack.*

Comment: If Possible can you suggest any other process of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample for saving PDF file.

`byte[] binaryData = (byte[])filedata.FILE_DATA;`

```
`File.WriteAllBytes("file.pdf", binaryData);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype System.Data.Linq.Binary then you could do something like:

```
byte[] bytes = filedata.FILE_DATA.ToArray();
```

Regards.